# warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

> rails s が急にできなくなってしまいました。。。
>
> 表示されたログです。

```
> bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
> /Users/Sean/Desktop/Renascence/bin/rails:6: warning: previous
> definition of APP_PATH was here Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]
> 
> The most common rails commands are:  generate    Generate new code
> (short-cut alias: "g")  console     Start the Rails console (short-cut
> alias: "c")  server      Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
> dbconsole   Start a console for the database specified in
> config/database.yml
>              (short-cut alias: "db")  new         Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
>              new application called MyApp in "./my_app"
> 
> In addition to those, there are:  application  Generate the Rails
> application code  destroy      Undo code generated with "generate"
> (short-cut alias: "d")  plugin new   Generates skeleton for developing
> a Rails plugin  runner       Run a piece of code in the application
> environment (short-cut alias: "r")
> 
> All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.
```

Answer (score 1):

エラーの原因は様々あるようです。

http://tic40.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/02/14/024415
http://xengineer.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/10/30/bin/rails%3A6%3A_warning%3A_already_initialized_constant_APP_PATH

以下のコマンドを打つと、本当のエラーの原因が表示されるようです。
まずはここから追ってみてはどうでしょう？

> rake rails:update:bin